# csslint command not executing in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, csslint

I am trying to execute following command from Jenkins window batch command

```
csslint --format=lint-xml file.css > result.xml
```

but every time it fail and give error: "csslint is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have set the Nodejs path correctly and above command executing from command prompt successfully.

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

First did you install csslint as a global?

npm install csslint -g

Second, I would then assume that csslint is not on your path.

in your batch program add this line above your app and see what your environment looks like.

```
env
csslint --format=lint-xml file.css > result.xml
```

that will print out your environment variables for that given jenkins run so you can take a look at your PATH variable and see if csslint is in any of those folders.

Comment: csslint is installed and path is also set in enviornment variable.
But adding evn in also not working. it giving the same error 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I think I forgot to ask you, is this version of jenkins installed on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes I am using Jenkins on windows.

Comment: ah well yea, env is not a windows command.  essentially you just need to print out your environment variables to the console so that jenkins can display it for you.